# firebase security rules: optional field that could be a null or a string?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

How to make firebase accept a key that could be a null or a string ? and yet the field is optional, since in security rules you canot ceck if (is) is null ?

```js
function dataCheckCreate(requestData) {
  return (
    // requestData.count required 
    requestData.count is number &&
    // requestData.src required 
    requestData.src is string &&
    // requestData.date optional !!
    // if available it could be a null or a string 
    (requestData.date == null || requestData.date is string)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last rule will be `true` when `date` is either equal to `null` or is a string. If you want that field to be optional then try:

```js
function dataCheckCreate(requestData) {
  return (
    requestData.count is number &&
    requestData.src is string &&

    // [date not present in data keys]       [date is string]
    (!('date' in requestData.keys()) || requestData.date is string)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant store **null** in a string field on firebase. The equivalent is to not store it at all.

Javascript will set the key **date** to undefined/null if it doesn't exist.
Since it's either null or string and optional, do you really need to check it? This would be a suitable check:

```
function dataCheckCreate(requestData) {
   return requestData.count && requestData.src

}
```

Comment: The field itself can be either `null` or a `string` unlike a SQL database.

Comment: Depends on what you mean. If you create a string field in a firestore document it cant have the "value" null, only an empty string

Comment: If the value if `null` in update request then field type will change to null unlike any SQL database where ORMs may replace null with empty string as default value or just don't allow update operation.